# .htaccess redirect from www to non-www is not working fine [i tried everything possible]

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

i have created a website with wordpress but when it came to SEO, i have this issue need to be fixed , the domain used to be linked to lawlytics.com subscription , in which i alredy canceled.
i installed wordpress and attached it to my domain, which is hosted on ionos.com , the problem is when i try opening my website http(s)://mywebsite.com it works fine with the installed wordpress, but when i try this http(s):[www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) it redirects to the old lawlytics subscription website. i have tried so many codes in .htaccess file like

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)(.+)
RewriteRule .* https://%1/$0 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteRule .* https://%1/$0 [R,L]
```

and this

```
    # Redirects from HTTP to HTTPS. We use %{SERVER_PORT} as it's more reliable than %{HTTPS}
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# Redirects www.example.com/... to example.com/...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```

But none of them worked while my .htacces file looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]  
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

this code is in the end of .htaccess.
my website have SSL installed already.

Comment: Try looking on ionos if the sub domain www.{your domain} points correctly to your new wordpress installation...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting anywhere (or edit if exists) in `wp-config.php` file:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://www.mywebsite.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.mywebsite.com' );
```

It worked for me a lot of times after moving website to new URL, but it depends on case.